# Node.js. Export a signed cookie to JSON

Tags: json, node.js, session, cookies

I have a signed cookie that can be viewed with console.log(req.cookies) and it's in this form:

```
{ 
    'connect.sid':'s:qX4ZrttrjydtrjkgsdghsdghrewynZj4Ew2OUh.tTSILkcvgsegsegsegsr99gmW5
0XLcJefM'
}
```

Since I know the cookie, but I also know the secret, is there a way to convert this from this format to it's JSON format with all it's fields like (name, value, URL, path, domain, expires, httpOnly, etc....).

I know that a Chrome plugin called EditThisCookie can do just that. So i guess it's possible to do it myself from my node application. I just don't know how.

It's also useful to state I am using Passport.js and OAUTH2 authentication.

Comment: I think I get what you want, I do that wit JWT signing and verifying: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken

Comment: Thanks! And you retrieve the values for all the fields with this method?

Comment: You use JWT.sign to create the token and JWT.verify return the object in it's payload.

Comment: Thanks! I read the docs. Will not the extra token ruin the integrity of my cookie? In the jwt.sign(), as a payload do i put the value of my cookie? Do i provide extra options?

Comment: Could you please provide some code for this? And i will  vote positive and will select your answer as the suggested one

Answer (score 1):

First, I use Passport.JS, Passport-JWT and JWT:

```
$ npm i -s passport passport-jwt jsonwebtoken
```

In the app.js file (supposing you are using Express.JS) you make the 
passport configuration

```
const passport = require('passport');

// TODO in case we cache need to to verify cache first
passport.use(new passportJWT.Strategy({
    'secretOrKey': 'a secret string, longer than this one', // The secret mut be the same all the times
    'jwtFromRequest': passportJWT.ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken()
  }, (payload, done) => {
    // note that if the token is invalid an error will be thrown, else
    // payload will be set as req.user here
    done(null, payload);
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
```

Than, use passport.authenticate in  the routes with controlled access:

```
app.get('/home', passport.authenticate('jwt', {'session': false}), dashboard);
```

In your login method, after success you bestow a token to the user, with the data you want tou be keept in the payload:

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
// Here you choose the data tha will be on your payload
jwt.sign({'id': user._id, 'username': user.username, 'email': user.email}, 'a secret string, longer than this one');
```

At last you can access the data through req.user int the routes that require authentication

Comment: Thanks a ton my friend! But i already am using passport-facebook strategy and i already have a cookie. So will this method work still?